# C# Asp.net - Use same information in multiple action methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I am confused and want to know the best practice for the use `same information` in `multiple action` methods. I have five values that I want to use in multiple `action` methods. I have `model` class which have that five values.

Currently I am storing data into session and getting that data in every `action` method where I need It.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Model model){
    Session["A"]=mode.a;
    Session["B"]=mode.b;
    Session["C"]=mode.c;
    Session["D"]=mode.d;
    Session["D"]=mode.d;
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Action1(){
    Label1.Text=Session["A"];
    Label2.Text=Session["B"];
    Label3.Text=Session["C"];
    Label4.Text=Session["D"];
    Label5.Text=Session["E"];
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Action2(){
    Label1.Text=Session["A"];
    Label2.Text=Session["B"];
    Label3.Text=Session["C"];
    Label4.Text=Session["D"];
    Label5.Text=Session["E"];
}
```

So simply my question is Can I pass that `object` of model class in every action method? Or there is any other best practice to use that `object of the model` class in every `action` method or using the `session` is better way ?

My all `action` method's `views` uses the same `model class.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the model itself within the `Session`, rather than storing each property of that object, makes storage a little easier perhaps.

```
Session["myModel"]=model;

Label1.Text=((Model)Session["myModel"]).a;
```

Without persistence of that information outside of the `Session`, there would be no other way to access the object on multiple, distinct `GET`s

Comment: But session may be effect the server and app performance. If there is 1M user is current accessing the website and I storing that data into session so the load on the server may be increased. No doubt the in session I am storing maximum `1KB` data.

Comment: If you intend to have that many users, you will need to use some kind of shared storage for Session regardless as it is highly unlikely that you will be able to run it from a single server. You can run Session information from a database and the impact of doing so is unlikely to be anything larger than a custom persistence implementation.

Comment: Redis cache session state provider is better option for shared and persistence session for the large number of users. Find the detail implementation on link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider/

Comment: That would depend if users want to hook up to azure, which I believe is where this lives. Great option if you are there, another dependency that can be implemented simply on a standard server set-up if you are not.